# Why does HDFS Split Files into Blocks?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to understand the benefit's attained by HDFS splitting files in to blocks.

I would have expected increased read performance resulting from parallelism by concurrent reads to multiple blocks.  However, I keep reading papers saying that reads/writes from/to HDFS are actually slower across the board than a single file on a local file system.

What performance benefits are achieved by HDFS splitting files into blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I keep reading papers saying that reads/writes from/to HDFS are actually slower across the board than a single file on a local file system.

If you can read a file on one machine then you don't need Hadoop. Hadoop is a distributed processing framework for huge datasets.

HDFS splits files into blocks because it's designed to handle files that are too big to be processed on one machine. It's not about increasing processing speed over small files, it's about giving you a way to process files that you couldn't process on one machine.

Comment: Ok this is a good start!! So if I have a directory with 100 large csvs, what is occurring differently behind the scenes if I read the file locally with a script.py vs. in HDFS?  And secondly, what changes if instead of script.py I use Spark?

Comment: @Dumbledore__ The fact that you use CSV files or Python script doesn't really matter. The HDFS client interaction is what matters. Spark itself can run locally (across multuple CPU cores), or it can be scheduled on a remote cluster such as YARN/Kubernetes. From there, the individual HDFS blocks would be processed in parallel. If you are using CSV, though, you'd usually be better with just an RDBMS since HDFS prefers other formats like Parquet or ORC

Comment: @OneCricketeer understood, only using CSV in the raw layer of the data lake, everything beyond that would be delta/parquet!  Just trying to understand the barriers that are handled by HDFS specifically, as well as how spark reads from HDFS.  Sounds like spark executors read blocks in parallel.  This is helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, blocks fit well with replication for providing fault tolerance and availability. HDFS replicates each block to a small number of physically separate machines & in the event of a failure, only those blocks need to be re-replicated from across their alternative locations to other live machines.